# Question regarding Continuity of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $ f: R^2 \to R $ defined by

$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases} 1, &x\geq 0\\ 
f(x,y)=x+y, &x < 0
\end{cases}$

The $f$ is

A.Continuous on $R^2$

B.Discontinuous only at one point on the non negative Y - Axis

C.Continuous only at one point on Y-Axis

D.Continuous only on set ${(x,y) \in R^2 : x \neq 0}$

I think A is wrong because $f$ is discontinuous at origin.B is wrong because $f$ is continuous on entire non negative Y Axis. C is also wrong because $f$ is continuous on entire positive Y axis. So I left with D. I am not sure though

Thanks

Comment: How is $f$ continuous on the entire $y$ axis if it is not continuous at the origin?

Comment: i meant positive Y Axis

Comment: Is $f$ continuous at the point $(0,\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: @uniquesolution i think yes

Comment: Well, it is not continuous at $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, because the limit of the function along the seqeunce $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2})$ equals $1$, whereas the limit along the sequence $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2})$ equals $\frac{1}{2}$. As both sequences tend to $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, the function is not continuous there. So now revise your answer.

Comment: @uniquesolution so f is discontinuous on entire Y Axis

Comment: @uniquesolution so answer is D

Answer (score 0):

I'm of two minds about this problem, but I'll give what I think is the right answer first.

f is clearly continuous everywhere not on the Y axis. So what about the Y axis? There is only one point where continuity is possible: where Y=1. There are three definitions of continuity that say that f is continuous at (0,1). One of them is that any sequence going to this point will have its image converge to 1.

Here's where I argue with myself. First of all, you haven't given the solution above as an option. Second, there is a neighborhood definition of continuity at a point that fails. If the pre-image of every neighborhood of a point is a neighborhood, then f is continuous at that point. Well, the pre-image of every open disk around (0,1) is not open: it includes the closed right half plane unioned to a strip in the left half plane.

If this second interpretation holds, then indeed D is your answer.

Comment: As the function is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you want to take a pre-image of an open interval (one-dimensional) around the number $1$ on the real line. The correct answer is actually C.

Comment: @uniquesolution how is C answer. i think it is not continuous on Y Axis

Comment: It is continuous at exactly one point of the $y$ axis, namely, $(0,1)$.